# Multiple paragraphs next to Font-Awesome icon and vertically-centered

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to position two paragraphs next to a Font Awesome icon and have them vertically centred too.

Using the below I have managed to get what I want but this is not responsive. If I start to shrink the screen, the text in the paragraphs becomes too long and then the div wrapping the paragraphs moves onto the next line. I would like the paragraph text to wrap whilst still being vertically centred.

For quickness I have just used the style tags for CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-4x fa-border" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"></i>
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; width: auto;">
    <p>sdfsdfd fsdfsdfsdfsdfd fdfsdfsdfsdfsd fsdfsddfdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdsdfd fsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsddfsdfs</p>
    <p>sdfsdfdf sdfsdfsdfsdfdf dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sddfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd fsdsdfd fsd fsd fsdf sdfs dfsddf sdfs</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code to your body:

```
 <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-4x fa-border" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"></i>
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; width: calc(100% - 109px);word-wrap: break-word;">
    <p>sdfsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfsdfs</p>
    <p>sdfsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfsdfs</p>
    </div>
```

Here is the preview link: https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/aVzoPd

I update for you avoiding fixed size..

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-4x fa-border" style=" "></i></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle; word-break: break-all;">
            <p>sdfsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfsdfs</p>
            <p>sdfsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddfsdfs</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**here is update link :**
https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/XzJWdK

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That seems to work thanks. I'm always keen to avoid hardcoding widths in the styles so is there anyway to avoid doing the calc(100%-109px)? If the size of the icon were to change, then this style would break.

Comment: I update for you avoiding fixed size..

here is update link :
https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/XzJWdK

Comment: Thank you. Why is it that `width: auto` doesn't work in this scenario? I didn't think it would require changing the display type to table.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT based on comment:**

[**Float solution Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/r2xuze7h/5/) (text will wrap below icon though)

---

You could use flex for that, note that in your scenario you are using very long text without spacing, which will prevent the browser from correctly wrapping it, added a few spaces to text here and there.

I'd suggest re-working your HTML to the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-4x fa-border" style=""></i>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>sdfsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdf dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sddfdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdsdfdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sddfsdfs</p>
    <p>sdfsdfdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdfd fsdfsdfsdfsd fsdfsddfdfsdfsdfsdfs dfsdfsdsdfdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsddfsdfs</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then simply add `display: flex;` to `.wrapper` via CSS.

**[See working resizable snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/r2xuze7h/)** (once on it, re-run for proper displaying)

Screens below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah good spot thanks. In my actual code I have both paragraphs filled with words separated by spaces. Just wanted some placeholder text for anonymity. I need really to support IE10 so have avoided using flex where possible. If this is the only way then will have to go flex.

Comment: Tophat, added a float solution above, hope helps. (once on the fiddle, re-run it, duno why it displays incorrectly on load)